# Error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, database, methods, dto

---

### SOLVED

---

I'm using DTO to map my DB to a Java object.

I had an error like this  `doku.eds2.dto.Transaction.getListedStatus()Ljava/lang/Character;`

I have checked my Transaction.java file, it contains the getListedStatus() method.

```
@Column(name="listed_status", length=1)
public Character getListedStatus() {
    return this.listedStatus;
}

public void setListedStatus(Character listedStatus) {
    this.listedStatus = listedStatus;
}
```

and also my table contains this field :

```
          Column           |            Type             | Modifiers 
listed_status              | character(1)                |
```

How can I fix this error?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Are you running this code in a stand alone application, or are you inside a container like JBoss or Websphere which could be messing with your classloaders? Are you building with Maven, or with some other technique?

Comment: im using jboss 5.1.0 GA Erica.

Comment: i deploy my ear file and my DTO.jar file to jboss.

Comment: Does your ear file contain any Hibernate jars, or jars for libraries which are also provided by JBoss?

Comment: thanks erica for your response. i have found the problem. the problem is the other ear project including the dto file. so jboss read dto from dto in my other project. thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

This sort of error often happens if you have two different versions of a class, one with the method and one without. If the one without the method ends up in the classpath earlier than the one with, then you will get an error like this.

Make sure that your classpath does not contain any other classes of the type "doku.eds2.dto.Transaction". If you're in Eclipse, you can do this by pressing Ctrl-Shift-T and entering the class name into the search. If you get multiple matches, you probably have a class path or dependency problem.

Comment: actually i can assure there is only 1 Transaction class on my project. is there anything reason?